# KDevelop include QtGui not found

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, kdevelop

I'm trying to learn how to use KDevelop on my Ubuntu 16.04 to write C++ code, and I installed it by doing this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdevelop
```

but after it is done installing and I'm trying to make a new project, and the lines at the top that says

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

and

```
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QMenu>
#include <QtGui/QMenuBar>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
```

are all returning errors saying that the included files are not found? And ask me to add a custom include path. I checked my KDevelop version on the terminal and it says I have Qt, or at least I think that's what it meant.

```
~$ kdevelop --version
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.16
KDevelop: 4.7.3
```

But then when I run

```
~$dpkg --list libqt4-dev
~$dpkg --list libqt4-core
~$dpkg --list libqt4-gui
```

and it says none of them are installed. I'm so confused. Do I have the right Qt or not? How do I get KDevelop to find the correct Qt path? Should I maybe just install all the libqt4-whatever and try again?

Comment: Fix your compilers include paths and install the dev packages for the version of Qt that you need.

Comment: Are you going to use Qt? If not, then you don't need those includes, they are for Qt. Try to create a generic C++ project instead of a Qt project, or just remove the includes (and possibly fix your project file to not try to link Qt). And since you apparently don't know Qt, I would very much recommend learning plain C++ basics first, before trying to tackle a big framework like Qt.

Comment: I am apparently not going to need Qt. But I installed it already following the answer to another solution somewhere else before I saw your comment. Oh well. I thought Qt was needed because it showed up in the generated basic hello world template code in KDevelop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to distinguish between libraries that allow you to run a software and developer versions that allow to build new sotfware. Output of `kdevelop --version` states versions of the libraries which are used to run the application. In your system you are missing  `qttools5-dev` with its dependencies.

By the way, maybe you will try qtCreator? It is an IDE developed by Qt team, and if you install it just by `apt install qtcreator` than you will have all necessary dev libs.

Comment: I don't think `apt install qtcreator` will install any dev libs. It installs just the IDE.

Comment: To install Qt dev libs easily on Ubuntu (any Debian based?), command is `apt install qt5-default`. If OP really wants to start with Qt instead of just plain C++, that is...

Comment: I am totally using Qt Crerator now. And you're right, I did need to install qt5-default for some kit thingy when I try to build the program.